# Update a Cache value without changing original timeout in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I am basically creating a cache key at a certain point with a timeout of a week.

```
cache.set("myKey",myValue,timeout=604800)
```

I'd like a way to update this cache value without changing the original timeout value.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api), if I pass `None` the value is cached forever, and if I don't pass anything it defaults to what I have in my settings.

```
cache.set("myKey",myValue,timeout=?)
```

So how could I do this?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think this is possible with the Django API. Search here for questions about getting the current timeout value (which would be one way to update without changing the ttl).

Comment: The solution I thought about was adding a timestamp to my key as well. And when I am either get/set the value I check if it has been a week compared to now. But was wondering if there was an easier way

Comment: which cache type you using database cache ?

Comment: I am using Redis

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the value in the cache without changing the original timeout value, you can use the timeout=None parameter.

```
cache.set("myKey", myValue, timeout=604800)


cache.set("myKey", newValue, timeout=None)
```

By setting timeout=None, you are telling the cache to keep the key indefinitely until you explicitly remove it or until the cache is cleared. This ensures that the original timeout value remains unchanged while updating the cached value.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested this locally, and set timeout to 120, then set it again with None. And 5 minutes late my value is still there

Comment: If setting timeout=None doesn't work as expected in your local testing and the value still expires, it may be due to specific cache implementation or configuration.

Comment: My point is that the value does NOT expire, I want the value to expire after the initial timeout setting I set. And would like to edit the value without changing the original timeout value. I think that the documentation states that None, makes the value stay in cache indefinitely, I believe that is what is happening

Comment: I see your point now. you can use the following approach: from django.core.cache import cache current_timeout = cache.ttl("myKey") cache.set("myKey", newValue, timeout=current_timeout)

Comment: Didnt know about cache.ttl() that might work yes